# Play a short portion of a long video file

Tags: video, html5-video

I need to play a short portion of a long video.  I can't edit the video to cut the part I want out, because I'm going to have about 6,000 different segments and it'd take too long to make individual files (and it'd be an issue with storage space).

So, say I want to start the clip 120 seconds into the video and play it for a duration of 180 seconds.

Here's my code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Video</title>    

    <script src="Backend/build/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="Backend/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Backend/build/mediaelementplayer.css" />
</head>

<body>

<video width="720" height="480" id="player1" controls preload="none" >
    <source src="Backend/media/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="Backend/media/test.webm" type="video/webm">    
    <source src="Backend/media/test.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <object width="720" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Backend/build/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=Backend/media/test.mp4" />
    </object>
</video>

<script>
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML5 video tag you can use the javascript `currentTime` property to start at a point, and a `timeupdate` event handler to stop the video.

```
// Javascript

var starttime = 2000;  // start at 2 seconds
var endtime = 4000;    // stop at 4 seconds

var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.currentTime = starttime;

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (video.currentTime >= endtime) {
        video.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

For the flash video, it purely depends on what flash player you're using.

Please note that the **entire** video probably will be loaded and considering your question I assume that it's a pretty big video.

Comment: Thanks, Tim!

Like I said, I'm a novice.  I tried this out and it don't work.  Maybe you can tell me what I did wrong? Please?

I changed my header by adding a reference to the new js, like so:

...

<title>Video</title> 
 
    <script src="Backend/build/Timer.js"></script>
//then as shown above...


And then I had it linked to a JS with the syntax you gave me above.

Sorry, to be a pest.  I'm new at this and I'm not a programmer...

Comment: In your case, you should replace the line `var video = document.getElementById('video');` with `var video = document.getElementById('player1');` since the id of your video element is `player1`. That should do the trick! Don't worry about it, programming is difficult matter.

Comment: This didn't work. :-(  I'm truly stumped.  The files are hosted on a local server and not in the cloud.  Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a degree of control over the server you could seek into the media files.

Example:  Use [H264 Streaming Module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac) (Apache httpd, lighttpd, nginx, IIS).  The position in the stream is referenced in a query string.  Example:  `http://server/media.mp4?position=32` Big name open source Flash players (like JWPlayer) support this scheme too.

Note you'll need to ensure the media is encoded in a friendly manner--namely a smallish keyframe spacing value.

Comment: Thanks, but my files are hosted locally, not streamed.  I'm trying to create an interface to access them via a GIS system.  Any ideas?